# How do I name a structure using a variable?

Tags: c, data-structures, naming-conventions

This is got to be simple, but I can't figure it out.  How do I name a structure using a variable, for example...

```
 char *QueryName = "GetAirports";   
 Query QueryName = malloc(sizeof(Query) + RecordCount*sizeof(int));
```

where "Query" is the name of a structure. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I assume you're talking about programming in c?  You should probably make that clear :)

Comment: What do you actually want here? Do you want a new variable of type `Query` called `GetAirports`? Could you write the equivalent C code that you want?

Comment: Ok, next question:  do you mean you want to alias the structure Query (i.e. typedef)?  Perhaps something else?

Comment: Are you trying to look up which specific `struct` type to use when given a `char *` string of the _name_ of the structure you'd like to use?

Comment: typedef struct query
    {
      char *QueryName[25];
      int   RecordCount;
      int   ColumnCount;
      int   Results[];
    } Query;

Comment: I've defined a struct aliased as Query which I now want to populate with different query result sets, each set named differently eg "Get Airport", "GetRunways" etc.  How do I use a variable holding to nme these different instances?

Answer (score 1):

In C you have to either use `struct` keyword where you use struct types, or use a typedef, like this:

```
typedef struct query
{
  // ....
} query_t;

int main ()
{
  query_t *q = malloc (sizeof (query_t));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Might be good to show an example doing it the other way...meaning, struct query *q = malloc (sizeof (struct query));

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're attempting to recreate what is allowed in more dynamic languages, such as this PHP example:

```
$QueryName = "GetAirports";
$$QueryName = array(/*...*/);
```

Where by altering the value of `$QueryName` variable you can refer to another object?

If so, the simple answer is: you can't do that in C.

What you can do, however, is use a single variable to *point to* multiple instances at different times.

```
Query *query_ptr = &myFirstQueryObject;
query_ptr = &mySecondQueryObject;
/* etc */
```

However from your example code it appears you're simply wanting to allocate a structure?  If so:

```
typedef struct Query {
    /* fields here, e.g: */
    int id;
    int age;
} Query_t;

int main()
{
    Query_t *query = malloc(sizeof(Query_t));

    query->id = 1;
    query->age = 0;

    /* etc. */

    return 0;
}
```

Perhaps look up C structs and pointers.

**EDIT** so from further comments apparently you're wanting to create a map of `char*` *name* to `Query` object?  There are several approaches for this, but the simplest is to create two arrays:

```
char *names[];
Query *queries[];
```

As long as both arrays have the same number of elements, and the *n*th element in `names` corresponds with the *n*th in `queries`, you can iterate through `names` until you find your matching string, then use the current index to dereference the appropriate object in `queries`, or *vice versa*

Comment: Matt K, using your example, how can I replace *query with *QueryName which was earlier set as *QueryName = "Get Airports"?

Comment: @MonkeyBusiness you can't, because `*QueryName` is a pointer to character data; there is no way you can (meaningfully) use that variable to somehow "point to" the actual Query object.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I see the need to use the variable. Why not just do:

```
Query GetAirports = malloc(sizeof(Query) + RecordCount*sizeof(int));
Query GetRunways = malloc(sizeof(Query) + RecordCount*sizeof(int));
```

Since C is a statically-typed compiled language, the names of objects such as `GetAirports` and `GetRunways` here are used at compile time, but *do not exist* at runtime. Therefore, it is not possible to use, at runtime, the contents of a string variable to refer to an object by name.

Comment: Well, I can do that except I have several items I want to name GetAirports for example and I wanted to use a variable to do this.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "several items I want to name GetAirports". In C, only one variable (at the same scope) can have the same name. That is, the names of all variables at the same scope must be unique. You can't have two different things called `GetAirports`.

Comment: I was able to do this easily in Cold Fusion, but that isn't C to be sure. Let me think about this a bit more before I waste any more of your time...

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question in brief: You cannot. You cannot assign the names of identifiers at runtime. Identifiers are a compile-time concept that are not even visible in the compiled result (in general). C is not a reflective language and cannot at runtime invoke its own compiler, as it were.